# request.referrer works only for URLs on localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack

I'd like to get referrer url.
So far I've tried following methods:

```
request.referer
request.referrer
request.headers["HTTP_REFERER"]
```

They all work only when I follow by URL from my localhost:3000.
If I create link on external site `http://localhost:3000` and click on it, then all these methods return `nil`.

How to avoid such behavior and get actual referrer url even if user came from external site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with request.env['HTTP_REFERER'].

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Sadly, it didn't help either. Seems like `referer` and `referrer` are just a shortcuts for `request.env['HTTP_REFERER']` http://rdoc.info/github/rack/rack/Rack/Request:referer

Comment: What did you do to end up solving this? This does not work for me either.

Answer (score 0):

1. don't use webrick & make sure your site is not being run in development
2. to activate referral url make sure the link is embedded in another website. I just injected a link onto whatever webpages i am on like "stackoverflow" and click on the link from there

finally worked for me, below is the result of

   `p request.referer`

[image]